# how to set up a remote debug in tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat

please tell me .. how to set up a remote debug in Tc Server(Tomcat) ?

I have (Tc Server, Idea 8, Java 1.6)

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Start the tomcat instance using the `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh` script as follows:

```
./catalina.sh jpda start
```

Using idea look at the options of the server and search for remote, i don't know exactly i do not have it right now to check.

By the way see [tomcat's developing faq](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing) for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although tc-server is a variant of tomcat it’s not exactly the same.

In **windows** based installation you should go to your instance directory and locate the configuration directory, e.g. if my instance is myApp it will be something like 
C:\dev\runtimes\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.0\myApp\conf

Edit the file **wrapper.conf** and add the following lines at the end of the 
“# Java Additional Parameters” section
wrapper.java.additional.16="-Xdebug"
wrapper.java.additional.17="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5000,server=y,suspend=n"

16 and 17 are sequences and they should start with n+1 of your latest existing sequence. In my file it was:
 
wrapper.java.additional.15="-Xss256K"
So my tc-server will listen for debugers on port 5000 and will not suspend.

This option will not be valid in Linux environment as it does not have a wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You can setup remote debug of tomcat by adding

> set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -DJava.compiler=NONE
>   Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000

to your startup.bat file within  \bin location.

Then create a debug configuration in your IDE with below connection properties.

> Host: localhost     Port:8000

Start tomcat and run the debug configuration.